# Maven checkstyle JavaDoc variables

Tags: java, maven

I want to enforce that methods and classes have JavaDocs. So I added the following to my checkstyle.xml but the problem is, it wants me to javadoc variables. I tried to tell checkstyle to ignore it, but its not working.

```
<module name="JavadocMethod">
    <property name="scope" value="protected"/>
    <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    <property name="allowMissingJavadoc" value="true"/>
    <property name="allowMissingParamTags" value="true"/>
    <property name="allowMissingReturnTag" value="true"/>
    <property name="allowMissingThrowsTags" value="true"/>
    <property name="allowThrowsTagsForSubclasses" value="true"/>
    <property name="allowUndeclaredRTE" value="true"/>
</module>
<module name="JavadocVariable">
    <property name="scope" value="public"/>
    <property name="severity" value="ignore"/>
</module>
<module name="JavadocType">
    <property name="scope" value="protected"/>
    <property name="severity" value="error"/>
</module>
```

Here is how I have it in the pom

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${org.maven-checkstyle-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                <configLocation>check-style.xml</configLocation>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

 <reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>checkstyle</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you show how checkstyle is wired in to your pom? Are you following something like [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/custom-checker-config.html)?

Comment: Updated post to show you

Comment: Ok, so I figured out the problem is, that mvn site is not using my checkstyle.xml file, its using something else. If I run mvn clean install I do not see those errors

Comment: Out of curiosity, what was it doing? Was it using some other checkstyle.xml, or silently ignoring yours somehow?